# Postfix does not deliver to domains with only an "A" record

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

We have a very strange situation I don't quite understand. Our postfix server mostly delivers email just fine, but for a number of domains, there is an issue. Those domains are peculiar, as they only have an a record and no MX record in DNS.

The error I am getting is:

`host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=<DOMAIN> type=MX: Unknown error 0>`

Strangely enough, this is true -- because the MX lookup does fail. There's that A record though, that postfix seems to happily ignore.

We're currently running postfix 2.9.6 coming out of pkgsrc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the configuration you're looking for is

```
ignore_mx_lookup_error = yes
```

which will force an A record lookup when an MX lookup produces no response (as opposed to a response that says the record doesn't exist).

There's more information at [the postfix documentation site](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#ignore_mx_lookup_error), with a warning that it can result in mis-delivery of mail.

Comment: Are you using relayhost parameter in postfix main.cf file ?